# Removing Any Non-Specified Characters from an Excel Spreadsheet using a Macro

Tags: excel, character, vba

I'm trying to clean up a .CSV file in Excel by getting rid of any non-standard characters. The only characters I care about keeping are A-Z, 0-9, and a few standard punctuation marks. Any other characters, I'd like to delete.

I've gotten the following macro to delete an entire row when it finds a cell which contains any characters I haven't specified, but I'm not sure how to get it to actually delete the character itself.

```
Sub Replace()
Dim sCharOK As String, s As String
Dim r As Range, rc As Range
Dim j As Long

sCharOK = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789, `~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':"",./<>?™®"

Set r = Worksheets("features").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

' loop through all the cells with text constant values and deletes the rows with characters not in sCharOK
For Each rc In r
    s = rc.Value
    For j = 1 To Len(s)
        If InStr(sCharOK, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 Then
            rc.EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next rc

End Sub
```

I assume there's a fairly simple way to adapt this code to that function, but I'm not familiar enough with VBA to really know how to go about doing that. Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be `Range.Replace` like:

```
Sub test()
  Dim sCharOK As String
  sCharOK = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789, `~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':"",./<>?™®" & Chr(1)
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To 255
    If InStr(sCharOK, Chr(i)) = 0 Then
      ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:=Chr(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

looking at @ryguy72 answer also offers another way if only non-printable characters need to be deleted (at the question something like `µ²äöüßÉõ` will be deleted but this code will not) also assuming that there are **no formulas**:

```
Sub test()
  With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Value = Evaluate("TRIM(CLEAN(" & .Address & "))")
  End With
End Sub
```

Or directly run in Immediate window this one-liner:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = Evaluate("TRIM(CLEAN(" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address & "))")
```

Comment: Slick. way less code and leverages builtin code which should be much faster.

Comment: What about Unicode characters with codes greater than `FF`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld They can not be there because of "*I'm trying to clean up a .CSV file...*" and "[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669373/csv-how-to-include-double-byte-characters)"

Comment: I was one of the upvotes on your answer, because of its simplicity and speed.  Only pointing out a possible limitation, which may not even apply in this particular case.  However, csv files can contain those pesky characters, and they can be imported into Excel given the proper setup.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm sorry if my comments sound rude or something like that. I'm a very nice guy who isn't pretty good in speaking (writing) English.  I also upvoted your answer as it does exactly what is asked by the OP.

Comment: @DirkReichel I did not take yours that way, But I was concerned after writing them that my comments also would not be taken well (and English is my first language) :-)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I want "Comic" and "Terminator" font... that would help me :P

Comment: The Range.Replace method you posted worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would use a replace command on the original string every time I find an invalid char, changing that invalid char to null. Then replace the original cell value with the modified string. Something like this...

One possible way (tested)

```
Sub RemoveInvalidCharacters()
Dim sCharOK As String, s As String
Dim r As Range, rc As Range
Dim j As Long
Dim badchar As Boolean

sCharOK = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789, `~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':"",./<>?™®"

Set r = Worksheets("features").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

' loop through all the cells with text constant values and
' deletes the invalid characters not in sCharOK from each Value property
For Each rc In r
    badchar = False
    s = rc.Value
    For j = 1 To Len(s)
        If InStr(sCharOK, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 Then
            badchar = True
            s = Replace(s, Mid(s, j, 1), "")
        End If
    Next j
    If badchar Then
        rc.Value = s
    End If
Next rc

End Sub
```

Comment: `sCharOK` are all the chars which are ok. `Mid(s, j, 1)` is the actual char in the string to check. `InStr(sCharOK, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0` => the character at position `j` is not valid. `replace(s, j, "")` will then replace the numerical value `j` in the string `s`... I'm sure you want to run `s = replace(s, Mid(s, j, 1), "")` ;)

Comment: Thanks Dirk, i got so hung up on the formatting issue, my brain took a hard left down the wrong road. Logic was good, Syntax was lacking :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use regular expressions, thereby avoiding needing to examine each character in a loop.  (Although the regex engine has to do that).

The Regex pattern, explained below, contains your list of characters, and the character class used says match everything that is not listed.

If speed becomes an issue, you can use vba arrays to speed things up.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceNonStdChars()
    Const sPat As String = "[^\x20-\x7E\x99\xAE]"
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim R As Range, C As Range

Set R = Worksheets("features").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    For Each C In R
        C.Value = .Replace(C.Text, "")
    Next C
End With
End Sub
```

### Explanation of Regex Pattern

### [^\x20-\x7E\x99\xAE]

```
[^\x20-\x7E\x99\xAE]
```

- [Match any single character NOT present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\x20-\x7E\x99\xAE]`

  - [A character in the range between these two characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `\x20-\x7E`

    - [The character “ ” which occupies position 0x20 (32 decimal) in the character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html) `\x20`
    - [The character “~” which occupies position 0x7E (126 decimal) in the character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html) `\x7E`
  - [The character with position 0x99 (153 decimal) in the character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html) `\x99`
  - [The character with position 0xAE (174 decimal) in the character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html) `\xAE`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: But running for each cell, may be slower at the end. However, this dependes mainly on the count of cells.

Comment: @DirkReichel Absolutely correct.  If there were a lot of cells, I'd use VBA arrays.  But using the regex pattern will also remove all non listed characters including Unicode characters.

Comment: deleted my comment by accident: If the OP really want it (or is just bored enough) he can run my code with `ChrW` from -32768 to 65535. :P

Comment: @DirkReichel And we don't even know if it is necessary or not.  But I do like the simplicity of your posted solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this today, literally.  The script below worked perfect fine for me.

```
Sub Clean_and_Trim_Cells()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim s As String
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        s = c.Value
        If Trim(Application.Clean(s)) <> s Then
            s = Trim(Application.Clean(s))
            c.Value = s
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```