# Foreign characters not supported in excel

Tags: excel, csv, utf

I have downloaded a CSV file from Cloud storage and saved it to my desktop. I gave save as and chose CSV utf-8 as save type. My csv file contains Thai language and Chinese language in it. But while viewing in excel, it gives something gibberish which is neither of the two languages. Please advice

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Comment: Do using [Text-Import-Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for opening the CSV file in Excel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669373/csv-how-to-include-double-byte-characters/37694689#37694689. Or make sure the CSV file contains a UTF-BOM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462764/javascript-export-csv-encoding-utf-8-issue/42466254#42466254.

Comment: I have already stored the characters in UTF-8 but even then it is not showing the different language

Comment: As all the above linked solutions tell, storing the characters in UTF-8 is not sufficient to let Excel opening a CSV properly. Either text import wizard with `File origin. 65001 : Unicode (UTF-8)` must be used or the CSV must have a UTF-BOM.